# Swift 3 hide NSButton immediately after click

Tags: swift, cocoa

How can I have a button disappear after it's been clicked?

```
 @IBAction func onClick(_ sender: NSButton) {
        sender.isHidden = true;
        //...a lot of blocking instructions below this line

 }
```

The above works to a certain extent, as the "sender" / button is  hidden only after all of the instructions in the function have been processed. I have some **blocking IO** in the function (socket connections  etc.) and I want the button to disappear before all that happens.

I tried using both *outlets* and *sender*.

Comment: Have you tried dispatching UI changes on the main queue? `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { // UI changes }` Then going on to do your IO blocking...

Comment: What I did and seemed to work was to move the blocking IO in a      DispatchQueue.main.async { } statement and leave the sender.isHidden outside. I'm not sure it's the best approach, though?

Comment: My understanding is that UI changes should be dispatched on the main queue to give the elusion that things are happening in "realtime".  IO processes can then be performed on a separate background queue to avoid the UI from "freezing".  See "Queue Types" in GCD post from Ray Wenderlich https://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 @IBAction func onClick(_ sender: NSButton) {
    sender.isHidden = true;
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //...a lot of blocking instructions below this line
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve the desired effect by putting the "blocking" piece of code in the following statement (and pushing the .isHidden setting through immediately, in a synchronous fashion):

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async { /*code*/ }
```